# Load cell Arduino HX711 Fluctuating up

Tags: arduino

I built an Arduino Bathroom Scale With four 50 Kg Load Cells and HX711 Amplifier. Some of the load cell wires are connected together to form a Wheatstone bridge arrangement. I am using an Arduino MEGA 2560. I previously built the same scale on another station and it works perfectly. My new station is fluctuating up non-stop, even without any weight on scale.
This is my calibration:

```
#include "HX711.h"

#define LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN  3
#define LOADCELL_SCK_PIN  2

HX711 scale;

float calibration_factor = -6440; //-6440 worked for my previous scale setup

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("HX711 calibration sketch");
  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
  Serial.println("After readings begin, place known weight on scale");
  Serial.println("Press + or a to increase calibration factor");
  Serial.println("Press - or z to decrease calibration factor");

  scale.begin(LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN, LOADCELL_SCK_PIN);
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 0

  long zero_factor = scale.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
  Serial.print("Zero factor: "); //This can be used to remove the need to tare the scale. Useful in permanent scale projects.
  Serial.println(zero_factor);
}

void loop() {

  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor

  Serial.print("Reading: ");
  Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 2);
  Serial.print(" kg"); //Change this to kg and re-adjust the calibration factor if you follow SI units like a sane person
  Serial.print(" calibration_factor: ");
  Serial.print(calibration_factor);
  Serial.println();

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp == '+' || temp == 'a')
      calibration_factor += 10;
    else if(temp == '-' || temp == 'z')
      calibration_factor -= 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is different this time, the software or the electronic part?  Hopefully not both.  Just wondering what's different between your first project, which you say works perfectly, and this one.

Comment: Nothing is actually different. I am using same software and load cells. I checked everything and cannot seem to spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought some extremely cheap (5 for $10.00) HX 711 boards. I noticed the same thing that you did; value drifting upward. I checked the on board load cell power supply and it seems to be defective. The band gap reference voltage (VBG) which is supposed to be 1.25 volts is actually 1.9 volts, so the on board regulator is just sending the incoming 5 volts straight to the load cell; no regulation. The 5 volts probably drifts, and the voltage drop of the pass transistor on the HX711 probably changes with temperature. All 5 boards I bought act the same way. I may get less drift if I just short the emitter to the collector on the pass transistor. I'll try buying a "Real" board and see if it's better.

Dan